# Incorrect output after returning elements between dates from a list

Tags: java, list, element

I'm working on a problem where I have to return postcodes from a list based on the time they have been added. For example, the user sets 12-2 then all the post codes added between 12 & 2 would be returned.

I've written a method, although currently the output is not as expected. The expected output is to be only the post code such as:

```
26-006
15-150
```

Whereas now I have: `StringContainer{size=4, head=kod pocztowy kod pocztowy kod pocztowy kod pocztowy kod pocztowy kod pocztowy null 2023-01-09T21:34:44.197357200 2023-01-09T21:34:44.197357200 2023-01-09T21:34:44.197357200 2023-01-09T21:34:44.197357200 2023-01-09T21:34:44.197357200 null`

It returns the postcodes + time etc.

Could you advise how to fix this?

Here is my current code:

```java
public class StringContainer {
    private int size = 0;
    private StringElement head = new StringElement(null);
    private Pattern pattern;

    public StringContainer(String regex) {
        clear();
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    }

    public void clear() {
        head.setNext(null);
        size = 0;
    }

    public void add(String value) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
        try {
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                if (head.getNext() == null) {
                    head.setNext(new StringElement(value, null, LocalDateTime.now()));
                }
                StringElement last = head.getNext();
                while (last.getNext() != null)
                    last = last.getNext();
                ++size;
                last.setNext(new StringElement(value, null, LocalDateTime.now()));
            } else {
                throw new InvalidStringContainerPatternException("Nie maczuje się");
            }
        } catch (InvalidStringContainerPatternException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean delete(Object o) {
        if (head.getNext() == null) return false;
        if (head.getNext().getValue().equals(o)) {
            head.setNext(head.getNext().getNext());
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        StringElement delete = head.getNext();
        while (delete != null && delete.getNext() != null) {
            if (delete.getNext().getValue().equals(o)) {
                delete.setNext(delete.getNext().getNext());
                size--;
                return true;
            }
            delete = delete.getNext();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public Object get(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position > size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        StringElement find = head.getNext();
        for (int i = 0; i <= position; i++)
            find = find.getNext();
        return find.getValue();
    }

    public StringContainer getDataBetween(LocalDateTime dateFrom, LocalDateTime dateTo) {
        StringContainer result = new StringContainer(this.pattern.pattern());
        StringElement current = this.head.getNext();
        while (current != null) {
            StringElement currentWithDate = current;
            if (currentWithDate.getDateTime().isAfter(dateFrom) && currentWithDate.getDateTime().isBefore(dateTo)) {
                result.add((String) currentWithDate.getValue());
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StringContainer{" +
                "size=" + size +
                ", head=" + head;
    }
}
```

```java
public class StringElement {
    private Object value;
    private StringElement next;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    public StringElement(Object value, StringElement next, LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public StringElement(Object value) {
        this(value, null, null);
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public StringElement getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(StringElement n) {
        next = n;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
    }

    public void setValue(Object o) {
        value = o;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "kod pocztowy " + next + " " + getDateTime();
    }
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringContainer st = new StringContainer("\\d{2}[-]\\d{3}");

        st.add("02-495");
        st.add("01-120");
        st.add("05-123");
        st.add("00-000");
        st.add("Ala ma kota");
        st.add("Ala ma psa");

        for (int i = 0; i < st.getSize(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Kod pocztowy :" + st.get(i));
        }

        st.delete(0);  //usuwa "02-495"
        st.delete("00-000"); // usuwa "00-000"

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("po usunieciu");
        for (int i = 0; i < st.getSize(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Kod pocztowy: " + st.get(i));

        }
        getDateTimeMethod(st);

    }

    private static void getDateTimeMethod(StringContainer st) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime dateFrom = now.minusHours(2);
        LocalDateTime dateTo = now.plusHours(2);
        StringContainer stBetween = st.getDataBetween(dateFrom,dateTo);
        System.out.println(stBetween);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code isn't self contained (no main method, for example - nowhere that shows where /how you print the result), and part of it is a simple typo/bug (for example, on an empty list you set the same thing twice, once in `head.setNext`, then again later on). StackOverflow is not a debugging service. Essentially, if you foresee nobody ever asking this question in the future, then generally it's not appropriate for SO. Various discord channels and such around to talk you through it, though :)

Comment: The `toString` methods in each class specify how the objects should be printed.  If you want to print the `StringContainer` differently, you'll have to write some code to actually print what you want.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Ive added the main method where Im printing out the result.

Do you have any channels in mind where I could join to walk through with someone such problems in the future?

Comment: So the culprit is the line `System.out.println(stBetween);` right at the bottom of the main class.  That calls the `toString` method of `stBetween`, which in turn calls the `toString` method of its head.  You could replace that line with a loop which prints what you actually want.  Alternatively, you could change the `toString` methods in both classes.